ValueError: Space not allowed in string format specifier
I was modernizing some old % formatted string code via regex substitution to change:
# Old:
'Map:     % 20s' % name
# to New:
'Map:     {: 20s}'.format(name)

and was surprised to get this error:

ValueError: Space not allowed in string format specifier

As the same syntax is valid for numerics and this error did not yet show up on my search on stack overflow, I wondered why does an error happen in the new format?

Sitenotes:

I do not want to use f-strings (yet) because there are many similar lines and it looks much neater using format instead.


Related:

Other alignment characters:
ValueError: '=' alignment not allowed in string format specifier

Same problem for f-strings.
Space in f-string leads to ValueError: Invalid format specifier

String formatting: % vs. .format vs. f-string literal



Pythons modern string replacement syntax [[fill]align] requires an alignment character from "<" | ">" | "^" if a fill value is provided. ("=" is not valid when when formatting with a string).
The correct usage is now:
'Map:     {: >20s}'.format(name)`
# or as space is the default it can be omitted
'Map:     {:>20s}'.format(name)`

Careful be aware that this is not equivalent in all cases to the old % formatting style

In cases where the format string contains a single generic format specifier (e.g. %s), and the right-hand side is an ambiguous expression, we cannot offer a safe fix.
For example, given:
"%s" % val
val could be a single-element tuple, or a single value (not contained in a tuple). Both of these would resolve to the same formatted string when using printf-style formatting, but resolve differently when using f-strings:

val = 1
print("%s" % val)  # "1"
print("{}".format(val))  # "1"

val = (1,)
print("%s" % val)  # "1"
print("{}".format(val))  # "(1,)"

from https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/rules/printf-string-formatting/
